# how to get nested collections data from firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore collection like the following. I need to get the last stored `message`.

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- chat_rooms(collection)
        |
        --- chats(collection, the id for that collection is sender_reciever)
             |
             --- time_send: (millisecondsSinceEpoch)
             |
             --- sender:(string)
             |
             --- message:(string)
```

This is my `db` method to get the last messaeg

```
  getLastMessage(String chatRoomId) {
    return  Firestore.instance.
    collection('chat_rooms').document(chatRoomId)
        .collection('chat').orderBy('time_send',descending: false)
        .limit(1).get();
  }
```

Here I am calling it. `Chats` is a widget that returns the `sender` and `last_message`. Basically what I am trying to do is, for instance,  while using whatsapp the last message pops on home page.I am trying to do exact same thing.In that way, I could get the `username` too. The method below does not return actual user data. Since the collection `chat_rooms_id` has an id that is combination of `username_sender` and `username_reciever`. I am just removing the `reciever` which is the current user.And, the `sender` remains.

```
   return Chats(
                      username: snapshot.data.documents[index]
                          .data["chat_room_id"] // return chat_room id
                          .toString()
                          .replaceAll("_", "")
                          .replaceAll(Constants.signedUserName, ""),
                      chatRoomId:
                          snapshot.data.documents[index].data["chat_room_id"],
                      last_message: __db
                          .getLastMessage(snapshot
                              .data.documents[index].data[snapshot.data.documents[index]
                                  .data['chat_room_id'].toString()]
                              .toString()).toString()
                    );
```

The result is
[image: Result]

Comment: Hey there, can you also include the definition of `Chats()` and also how the method that runs `return chats()`is defined? As per the message `Instance of future`, it seems like some `async/await` or `then` keywords are missing. The above is expected behavior described in [1]. 
[1] https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#example-incorrectly-using-an-asynchronous-function

Answer (score 1):

First, create a class to store Chat info

```
class Chat {
  final String id;
  final time_send;
  final String sender;
  final String message;
  
  Chat({this.id, this.time_send, this.sender, this.message});
  
  
  static Chat fromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snap) {
    return Chat(
      id: snap.id,
      time_send: snap.get('time_send'),
      sender: snap.get('sender'),
      message: snap.get('message'),
    );
  }
}
```

Then, modify your Firestore query as below, use snapshots() instead of get() method

```
Stream<Chat> chat(String chatRoomId) {
  return  Firestore.instance.
    collection('chat_rooms').document(chatRoomId)
    .collection('chat').orderBy('time_send',descending: false)
    .limit(1)
    .snapshots()
    .map<Chat>((snapshot) {
       if (snapshot.size > 0) {
          return snapshot.docs.map((e) => Chat.fromSnapshot(e)).single;
       } 
 });
```

Comment: I am gettin errors like in chat class `id, sender, time_sed, message` is not defined for fromSnapshot() method.  Also in the query method there are some problems which `single ` is not deifned. My firestore version is `  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.0+1`

Comment: I modified the method like ```return snapshot.documents. map((e) => Chat.fromSnapshot(e)).single``` now it says `DocumentSnapshot cannot assign to Query snapshot` for `e`

Comment: Change fromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snap) to fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snap) method in Chat class